# How to find endpoint URL of an API Gateway in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I have made a few API Gateways in AWS.

At this point , I would like curl to the endpoint of each API Gateway in order to start testing. But, I cannot find the endpoint URL:

For example, via CLI, I ran:

`aws --profile dev apigateway get-rest-apis --output json`

I get: (no endpoint URL)

```
            "apiKeySource": "HEADER", 
            "description": "API one", 
            "endpointConfiguration": {
                "types": [
                    "REGIONAL"
                ]
            }, 
            "createdDate": 1570655986, 
            "policy": "{\\\"Version\\\":\\\"2012-10-17\\\",\\\"Statement\\\":[{\\\"Effect\\\":\\\"Allow\\\",\\\"Principal\\\":\\\"*\\\",\\\"Action\\\":\\\"execute-api:Invoke\\\",\\\"Resource\\\":\\\"arn:aws:FOOBAR\\/*\\/*\\/*\\\",\\\"Condition\\\":{\\\"IpAddress\\\":{\\\"aws:SourceIp\\\":[\\\"0.0.0.0\\/0\\\""]}}}]}", 
            "id": "foobar", 
            "name": "foobar"
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to deploy the APIs.
you find then the https address in the deployed stage.
or you can use a custom domain name